# Import a Flask project in PyCharm

Tags: python, flask, pycharm

I saw there is a [way to create a new Flask project in PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/creating-flask-project.html) that has the ability to resolve Flask extensions (`flask.ext.*` namespace) but I don't see how to import one that has been checked out from a VCS with existing structure. Any thoughts on this?

In my project I already import `flask_admin` instead of `flask.ext.admin` for example and PyCharm finds the modules well. But when I go to a class in `flask_foobar` for example, there the includes are `flask.ext.foobar` and referencing is lost.

Comment: How about using `from flask_foobar import FooBar`? It works with all IDEs without warnings.

Comment: I tried to elaborate my question. I already do that but when you dive into an include, further references are lost.